# CustomerError: Can't find required-server-files.json in build output directory

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, github, next.js, aws-amplify

I have an issue when I deploy our next js app to AWS amplify the build done but CustomerError occurs that blocks my deployment: here are my logs

```
2024-01-25T20:11:31.852Z [INFO]: 
2024-01-25T20:11:31.857Z [INFO]: Done in 175.65s.
2024-01-25T20:11:31.874Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2024-01-25T20:11:31.894Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2024-01-25T20:11:31.896Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2024-01-25T20:11:31.909Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
2024-01-25T20:13:18.327Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
2024-01-25T20:13:18.480Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2024-01-25T20:13:28.603Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
2024-01-25T20:13:28.703Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2024-01-25T20:13:28.715Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Can't find required-server-files.json in build output directory
2024-01-25T20:13:28.716Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-01-25T20:13:28.716Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Comment: Got the same at the end of successful build.

I use Next.js v14 with { output: "export" } config 

I run on custom build image with Node 20: public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:20.11.0

Comment: Same on my side with Amplify, still cannot find a solution

Answer (score 0):

in amplify.yml
it is because of
artifacts:
baseDirectory: "path_is_wrong"

base directory will start from appRoot that you provided in amplify.yml
and since it is next base directory's last folder should be something like "dist/apps/my-app/**.next**"

Comment: BuildSpec: |
        version: 1.0
        frontend:
          phases:
            preBuild:
              commands:
                - nvm use 18
                - yarn install
            build:
              commands:
                - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
                - yarn run build
          artifacts:
            baseDirectory: .next
            files:
              - "**/*"
          cache:
            paths:
              - node_modules/**/*




here i add the path of my build directory its look good but still get same error

Comment: im not an expert but can you try to change the files: - '*/' to 
files: -'**/*'

and/or 

baseDirectory: ./.next

Comment: BuildSpec: |
        version: 1.0
        frontend:
          phases:
            preBuild:
              commands:
                - nvm use 18
                - yarn install
            build:
              commands:
                - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
                - yarn run build
          artifacts:
            baseDirectory: ./.next
            files:
              - “**/*”
          cache:
            paths:
              - node_modules/**/*

Yeah I change this path but still got the same issue

Comment: https://ibb.co/8j4LdvQ


here you can see my complete BuildSpec steps is there anything that I missed?

Comment: that looks good to me.
yarn run build locally and check if .next folder is really in root of project
if it is there sorry pal i rlly don't know

Answer (score 0):

If you use Next.js with { output: "export" } config. Add 'next export" in package.json

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build && next export",  // Add next export
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
},
...
```

Amplify performs an automatic build based on the "scripts" in package.json.

next export is deprecated and replaced with "output": "export" since v13.3. However, However, amplify still decides how to build through "next export".

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem using nextjs with a SSG app.
what fixed it for me was changing the build script to
`"build": "next build && next export"`
which causes amplify to identify the app as SSG.
and then i added the actual build script (since next export is deprecated)
`"actualBuild": "next build"`
and ran the actual build script.